# detect for empty field in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, trim

I'm getting json data with a bunch of spaces as strings like this:

```
{
  appNumber: "       "
}
```

but at times i get this back

```
{
  appNumber: "123456"
}
```

I want to be able to detect when it doesnt have any numerical value in it and display a dash instead

so in my controller i have:

```
$scope.appNumber = function() {

        var appNumber = $scope.appNumber.trim();

        if (!appNumber) {
          return "-";
        }

        return $scope.appNumber;
      };
```

in my HTML:

```
<div ng-bind="appNumber()"></div>
```

Comment: you are calling trim on the current scope function. change the name of your variable you want to trim

Answer (score 2):

You are calling trim on the current scope function. change the name of your variable you want to trim

To return appNumber if it is a number or '-' try below

```
$scope.appNumber = function() {
    $scope.str = "12312";
    var x = + $scope.str;
    if (x.toString() === $scope.str) {
        return $scope.str;
    }
    return '-';
 };
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/11250/)